# Build hash of hashes from a single hash

Tags: perl

I have the following hash

```
my  %input_hash = (
    'test1' => '100',
    'test2' => '200',
    'test3' => '300',
    'test4' => '400',
    'test5' => '500'
);
```

What I need is to build a hash of hash from the above hash. I need to put the first 2 of the above key value pair into a key of the hash of hash. Better explained with this example.
Desired output:

```
my %expected_hash = (
1 => {
    'test1' => '100',
    'test2' => '200',

},
2 => {
    'test3' => '300',
    'test4' => '400',
},
3 => {
    'test5' => '500'
},
```

);

I would like the split to be dynamic. Example,if i need to split by 3, the desired output should be

```
my %expected_hash = (
1 => {
    'test1' => '100',
    'test2' => '200',
    'test3' => '300',
},
2 => {
    'test4' => '400',
    'test5' => '500'
},
```

);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using an index array built from number of keys in `%input_hash` and desired size set in `$chunk_size`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my  %input_hash = (
    'test1' => '100',
    'test2' => '200',
    'test3' => '300',
    'test4' => '400',
    'test5' => '500'
);

my $chunk_size = 2;
my @indexes = map {int($_ / $chunk_size) + 1} 0 .. keys %input_hash;
my %expected_hash;

for my $key (sort keys %input_hash) {
    my $index = shift @indexes;
    $expected_hash{$index}{$key} = $input_hash{$key};
}

print Dumper \%expected_hash;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
      '1' => {
               'test1' => '100',
               'test2' => '200'
             },
      '3' => {
               'test5' => '500'
             },
      '2' => {
               'test4' => '400',
               'test3' => '300'
             }
    };
```

Of course, as TLP mentioned, you have to sort `%input_hash` to achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a version that uses `splice` to get a dynamic number of elements. Note that you have to sort the keys in the hash, because hashes are unordered.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my  %input_hash = (
    'test1' => '100',
    'test2' => '200',
    'test3' => '300',
    'test4' => '400',
    'test5' => '500',
    'test6' => '600',
    'test7' => '700',
    'test8' => '800',
    'test9' => '900'
);

my $foo = foo(\%input_hash, 4);
print Dumper $foo;

sub foo {
    my ($href, $count) = @_;
    my @keys = sort keys %$href;
    my %hash;
    my $i = 1;
    while (@keys) {
        $hash{$i++} = { map { $_ => $href->{$_} }
            splice @keys, 0, $count };
    }
    return \%hash;
}
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = {
      '1' => {
               'test1' => '100',
               'test4' => '400',
               'test3' => '300',
               'test2' => '200'
             },
      '3' => {
               'test9' => '900'
             },
      '2' => {
               'test8' => '800',
               'test5' => '500',
               'test7' => '700',
               'test6' => '600'
             }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my ($expected_hash_key, $cnt, $L1, $L2) = (1, 1, "", "");
my %expected_hash;

# Change $LIMIT to required value. 2 or 3.
my $LIMIT = 2;

my  %input_hash = (
    'test1' => '100',
    'test2' => '200',
    'test3' => '300',
    'test4' => '400',
    'test5' => '500'
);

for (sort keys %input_hash) {
    $cnt++;
    $expected_hash{$expected_hash_key}{$_} = $input_hash{$_};
    if ($cnt == $LIMIT + 1) {
        $cnt = 1;
        $expected_hash_key++;
    }
}

for $L1 (sort keys %expected_hash) {
    print "$L1 ==> \n";
    for $L2 (sort keys %{ $expected_hash{$L1} }) {
        print "$L2 -> $expected_hash{$L1}{$L2}\n";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```